# How can I add even more bullet list levels?

Tags: google-docs

I have a very long bullet list with a lot of depth to the point that it gets very close to the far right of the page. Then I can no longer add any more bullets to the right.

I tried to increase the width of the page to see if I could add more depth to my list to the right, but I still can't.

Is there a way to add more bullet list levels?

You can see what I mean on the following image:

[image: Screenshot of a Google Documents with lots of indented bullet points]

As you can see on the image, I can no longer add J and K to the right of I.

Comment: Could you crop that image to have less whitespace? As it is it's hard to see.

Comment: how do you even get nested bullets?  When i try indenting either numbered or unnumbered bullets, it gets turned into a top-level unnumbered bullet!  Tab does the same thing!

Answer (score 5):

Here's a workaround and I know it's hacky.  If you're desperate like I was, it maybe worth considering...

Insert a table on a nested bullet point and you get to use 9 levels in that table.  As you go deeper, you can insert another table and get another 9 levels. There doesn't seem to be a limit to how many tables you nest.

[image]

Comment: Nice! To make it look invisible, you can select the borders and set the border weight to 0pt, as well as setting Table properties > Alignment > Cell padding to 0 (though it seems to have slightly too little space on the bottom?).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Google Docs does not offer nested bullets deeper than nine levels.

The best you can probably do is to adjust your tabs in the ruler at the top of your document for those last few levels.

[image: ruler]

Grab that downward pointing arrow and slide it to the left. That'll let you adjust the depth of your bullet items. (Putting the rectangle closer to the triangle will control how far from the bullet to the start of the text.)

It's a lot of manual work, you'll need to tweak it so it looks right, and everything after the magical ninth level will have the same bullet type. (Even if you right-click the bullet to change the bullet type, "I", "J", and "K" will all be changed because they're technically the same bullet level.) Plus who knows what havoc outdenting will cause.

I don't know what happens if you were to, say, take a Microsoft Word document with more than nine levels of bullets and import/convert it to Google Docs format.